# Train neural network with sentences of different length in a QA system

Tags: neural-network, word2vec, nlp-question-answering

I'm trying to implement a QA system following the instructions showed on this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.03609). I've correctly imported some datasets and converted the words in vectors with the word2vec method. After the word embedding there is the need to insert the questions and the answers in a CNN. What should be the size of the input Tensor given that each question/answer has a different length? (each question/answer is an array of vectors).

*Excerpt from paper:*

[image]

***q_emb*** is the question after the word embedding and **r_w_k** is a word vector of length **d**.

Which is the right value of ***M*** (the length of the Q/A) that should be used? Can you please show me some methods to solve this issue or simply give me some help? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Determine the maximum question/answer vector array length and make your input tensor of shape `(num_samples, max_qa_length, word_embedding_size)`. For questions shorter than `max_qa_length`, pad them with zero vectors at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And what about creating the Z vector? In your opinion, will be better to create it before giving it to the NN as a tensor or in the network?

Comment: You will want to do the padding before you feed it to TensorFlow, otherwise it will complain about the shape of your input.